# System.Threading.Tasks, lambdas, an error handler and object destruction

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a simple background cache updater method:

```
void StartBackgroundLookup( string username )
    {

        Action action = () =>
                            {
                                (...)//A 'lengthy' lookup here
                                Cache.Set(key, xxx, cachePolicy);
                            };

        Task.Factory.StartNew(action).ContinueWith(task => MyErrorHandler(task.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }
```

The error handler is a private non-static method:

```
    private void MyErrorHandler(Exception error)
    {
        //msg logged here
    }
```

Is my understanding correct that the object who StartBackgroundLookup is a method of will not be finalized until the task finishes even if it goes out of scope (the reason being Cache is used in the lambda and and an instance MyErrorHandler is used with ContinueWith)?

What would happen if it was a disposable object and dispose was called?

Comment: dispose() will "clean up" the objects resources,managed and unmanaged,before it falls out of scope,you can make your type disposable and call the method inside using syntax

Comment: If the dispose method is called explicitly or via the using keyword you will end up with a disposed object. But if not, a reference will be kept to that object that will prevent the Garbage Collector from finalizing the object.

Comment: you can force GC GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dispose` is just like any other method -- it has a particular meaning to .NET coders that it cleans up resources, but the CLR itself doesn't treat it specially. The object will remain alive and unfinalized until there are no references to it, including the one in the capture.

Now, "alive" is a relative term... using the object might result in a `ObjectDisposedException` if it is coded robustly, or perhaps seemingly working undefined behavior if not.

Answer (score 0):

The object that owns `StartBackgroundLookup` may be garbage collected before your `Task.Factory.StartNew(action)` completes. These two are not related by anything UNLESS you have a reference to the object itself, inside `action` (as a closure for example, like `var clo = this;` and using `this.Something` inside action does not prevents the object - which can be referred by `this` - from being garbage collected).

Comment: What do you mean 'StartBackgroundLookup may be garbage collected'?